# Set default font size in Emacs 23.4?

Tags: emacs, fonts

I use the following in my .emacs to set my default font to Ubuntu Mono:

```
(set-face-attribute 'default nil :font "Ubuntu Mono")
```

However, the defauly font size is too tiny for me. In my menubar I see Options->Set Default Font..., but the changes I make there does not propogate to my next session.

Should I be setting something in .emacs to set default font size? (I like it to be 24)

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/294664/how-to-set-the-font-size-in-emacs

Comment: I think it's just because you didn't "save" the setting (I remember there is another option in the menubar to save the setting.)

Comment: @harish.venkat Nice find. We can't actually close as a duplicate of a post on another site, but I used that answer to write one here

Answer (score 3):

An answer to a [similar Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/294664/309308) mentions that another argument to `set-face-attribute` is `height`, which takes an integer representing tenths of a point. So to make it 24pt, you would use:

```
(set-face-attribute 'default nil :font "Ubuntu Mono" :height 240)
```